Django me dice que no puede iniciar el servidor por que falta un archivo, pero ese archivo no existe
estoy haciendo una pagina web que incluye, java, json y lo estoy usando con django.
El tema es que estoy configurando mi carrito compras, tengo dos carpetas Core y Unnas, y en Unnas tengo los templates y de más, el problema es que inicialmente tenia una carperta llamada Unnitas, pero la borre por cmd con el comando
rmdir /s /q Unnitas
me dice que efectivamente esta borrado y que no se encuentra dentro de los archivos y eso lo verifique en con powerShell ya que me muestra:
        Length Name

          Core
          css.css
          imagenes
          JavaScript
          json
          myvenv
          node_modules
          package.json
          Unnas
          Contacto.html
          0 db.sqlite3
          prueba.html
--el resto --

pero me sigue saliendo el error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Unnitas'
y no se por que, revise archivo por archivo y no existe referencia a Unnitas, si me pueden ayudar por favor.

El error es propio de un import, tiene toda la pinta de que algún módulo está intentando importar el paquete  Unnitas y como lo has eliminado no lo encuentra. Deberías agregar la traza completa del error, es tan o más importante que el error mismo, en ella viene especificada toda la pila de llamadas que al final desencadena la excepción y nos debería permitir identificar el módulo, linea y llamada concreta  que está intentando hacer ese import. Sin ello y sin poder reproducir el problema  es complicado que podamos dar alguna indicación no geneŕica.
